# how to pass params to nested navigators using React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

Can't pass params to the nested navigator. I keep getting errors undefined is not an object evaluating `route.params.data`

I do have different stack navigators for homeDrawer and LiveModeDrawer. I am using React navigation version 6. I looked over the documents however what I have read is not working.

app.js

```js
<Drawer.Navigator>
  <Drawer.Screen
    name="HomeDrawer"
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
    component={MainNavigator}
  />
  <Drawer.Screen
    name="LiveModeDrawer"
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
    component={LiveModeStackNavigator}
  />
</Drawer.Navigator>;
```

todo.js

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate("LiveModeDrawer", {
  screen: "LiveModeAlertOnly",
  params: { data: "jane" },
});
```

live.js

```js
export default function LiveModeAlertsNotifications({ route, navigation }) {
  const { data } = route.params;
  console.info(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the second parameter already are the Params

Change this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('LiveModeDrawer', {
        screen: 'LiveModeAlertOnly',
        params: {data: 'jane'},
      });
```

To:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('LiveModeDrawer', {
       data: 'jane,
      });
```

Or:

```
export default function LiveModeAlertsNotifications({route, navigation}) {
   const {data} = route.params.params; // Add another params
   console.info(data)
```

Comment: still not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to pass the prop into a sub component